# Params disappearing when using Tempus dominus bootstrap4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use the Tempus Dominus Datetime picker in my app.  Everything seems to work fine, but when I try to convert the submitted string into a datetime object in my controller, I get a TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String).  I've also tried to puts the parameters into the logs, but get a blank line.  The odd thing is, during the submission of the form, the parameters do seem to be present.

> Processing by EventsController#create as HTML
>    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", >"authenticity_token"=>"yuP08tdkavDAzcbJImZXeL0EZ1dp6D13dnLyW/lU+frPVej0tiUmavI>0GKvs66z7+ca2GynI1WWs2d5aSJX5zA==", "event"=>{"title"=>"aaaaa", >"game"=>"bbbb", "start_time"=>"02/21/2020 1:26 PM", "end_time"=>"02/28/2020 >10:46 PM", "description"=>"sasasa"}, "button"=>""}

Here's all relevant code.

Controller:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @event = Event.new
  end

  def create 
    @user = current_user
    if @user
      @user.events.create(title: params[:title], game: params[:game], 
                          start_time: time_parse(params[:start_time]), 
                          end_time: time_parse(params[:start_time]),
                          description: params[:description])
    end
  end

  private 
  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:title, :game, :start_time,:end_time, :description)
  end

  def time_parse(time)
    DateTime.strptime(time, '%m/%d/%Y %M:%S %p')
  end
end
```

View:

```
 <div class="col-lg-6">
            <%= form_for @event, url: events_path do |form| %>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                  <%= form.text_field :title, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Party Title" %>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                  <%= form.text_field :game, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Game" %>
                </div>
              </div>



              <div class="row">
                <div class='col-md-6'>
                  <div class='form-group'>
                    <%= form.label :start_time, 'Start Date and Time', class: 'control-label' %><br>
                    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
                      <%= form.text_field(:start_time, 
                        value: form.object.start_time ? form.object.start_time.strftime('%B %d, %Y %I:%M %p') : nil, 
                        class: "form-control datetimepicker-input", data: {target:"#datetimepicker1"}) %>
                      <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-calendar-plus"></i></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-6'>
                  <div class='form-group'>
                    <%= form.label :end_time, 'End Date and Time', class: 'control-label' %><br>
                    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2" data-target-input="nearest">
                      <%= form.text_field(:end_time, 
                        value: form.object.end_time ? form.object.end_time.strftime('%B %d, %Y %I:%M %p') : nil, 
                        class: "form-control datetimepicker-input", data: {target:"#datetimepicker2"}) %>
                      <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker2" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-calendar-plus"></i></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
              </div>
                <%= form.text_area :description, class: "form-control", size: "24x6", placeholder: "Describe your meetup"%>
              </div>

              <div class="text-center "><%= form.button "Sign up", class: "sub-but" %></div>
            <% end %>


          </div>
```

Javascript for view:

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  format: 'MMMM D, YYYY h:mm A',
  stepping: 15,
  minDate: Date(),
  maxDate: new Date(Date.now() + (365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)),
  sideBySide: true,
  icons: {
    up: 'fas fa-arrow-up',
    down: 'fas fa-arrow-down',
    previous: 'fas fa-chevron-left',
    next: 'fas fa-chevron-right',
    close: 'fas fa-times'
  },
  buttons: {showClose: true }
});

$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
  format: 'MMMM D, YYYY h:mm A',
  stepping: 15,
  useCurrent: false,
  sideBySide: true,
  icons: {
    up: 'fas fa-arrow-up',
    down: 'fas fa-arrow-down',
    previous: 'fas fa-chevron-left',
    next: 'fas fa-chevron-right',
    close: 'fas fa-times'
  },
  buttons: {showClose: true }
});
$("#datetimepicker1").on("change.datetimepicker", function (e) {
  $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker('minDate', e.date);
  console.log(e.date);
});
$("#datetimepicker2").on("change.datetimepicker", function (e) {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker('maxDate', e.date);
});
```

Comment: Looks like the values being sent over are a string, what is the column in the date base looking for, date object? Or other way around?

Comment: The time_parse method in the controller should be creating a datetime resource before the event object is saved.  The error indicates that only nil is reaching time_parse, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not linking to the params correctly, also I noticed you have the `:start_time` going into both in your code above, I assume that is a typo so I changed it in my answer. If it isn't a typo then keep that as is.

```
...
start_time: time_parse(params[:event][:start_time]), 
end_time: time_parse(params[:event][:end_time]),
...
```

Comment: That was it.  The attributes were inside the events hash inside the params hash.  What a goof.  Thanks!